# How to power servo motors?

Tags: power-supply, motor, lithium-ion

I built a robotic arm consisting of three MG 996R servo and three MG 90S servo. How to power them externally? I used three batteries of 3.7 volt but they are getting discharged left and right.

Comment: So what is the Whr rating of your batteries?  That will let you estimate the run time.  (So do the batteries discharge differently up and down??)

Comment: What does *they are getting discharged left and right* mean?

Comment: Get a bench DC power supply.

Answer (score 1):

3*3.7v is almost 12v. Do yourself a favor and buy an off-the-shelf mains to 12V PSU. If you already have USB-C PD bricks around, you can easily get a USB-C PD decoy that can trigger different output voltages and deliver up to 5A (the latest standards support 20V at 5A which is more than enough for most of your needs).

Answer (score 0):

Your current 3.7 V batteries might be inadequate in terms of voltage and capacity. Consider switching to a higher-capacity battery, like a 2S or 3S Li-ion, which can provide higher voltage and more capacity.
Ensure the battery can provide the required current continuously without significant voltage drop.

Consider Using a BEC (Battery Eliminator Circuit):

A BEC can decrease the voltage from a higher-voltage source (like a 2S or 3S Li-ion battery) to the appropriate level for your servos, usually 5 V or 6 V.
It also ensures that your servos receive a consistent voltage, even as the battery voltage varies.